# User Profile Synchronization Service - STARTING

Tags: sharepoint, synchronization, user-profile

I have installed sharepoint server 2010 and created many sites , added about 500 users in the AD , given the appropriate permissions to the groups, everyone is normally loging in using his credentials.

The wird thing i cannot understand is that whenever i try to start the "User Profile Synchronization Service" is freezes for a long time to "STARTING" mode.

After that it is "STOPPED" again.

Also.

1)my AD users have emails stored, but sharepoint is not able to see these email. Whenever i try to create an alert it says that there is no email address.

2)using the server (This machine) noone else except for the Administrator  (account) can login. NO ONE

If i logged in over the internet or my lan, anyone can login using his credentials, as i mentioned before.

User Profile Service is working ok.

When entering (CA) Profile Service Application , i get this

Profiles

Number of User Profiles

6

Number of User Properties

68

Number of Organization Profiles

1

Number of Organization Properties

15

Audiences

Number of Audiences

1

Uncompiled Audiences

0

Audience Compilation Status

Idle

Audience Compilation Schedule

Every Saturday at 01:00 AM

Last Compilation Time

Ended at 3/24/2012 1:00

Profile Synchronization Settings

User Profile Sync is not currently

Synchronization Schedule (Incremental)

Every day at 01:00 AM

When entering the "CA">"User Profile Synch Service", in the "select User Profile Application" dropdown box , there is nothing.

after that is an account named "dbaccess" , for which i have to enter the credentials. I have made this account an AD administrator.

I am available to provide you ANY other information, screenshot or even access to the machine , in order to help me with this issue.

It is the most difficult issue i have faced, since i first started my sharepoint project.

Looking forward to ANY help...

Answer (score 0):

If you have 500 users in AD and the Number of profiles you see in the UPSA is just 6 then you may not be pointing to the right Ad OU in your connection